# How to align images with textwrap in css

Tags: html, css, styles

I have a text followed by images right and left but the image is not aligned properly like below scrrenshot

[my image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jLXOd.png)
Following is the code

```css
.textWrapFaq {
  float: right;
  margin: 10px;
  margin-bottom: auto;
}
.textWrapFaqLeft {
  float: left;
  margin: 10px;
  margin-bottom: auto;
  clear: right;
}
```

```html
<img img-cache src=\ "assets/images/c1.gif\" alt=\ "personalized_list_of_Xpert_doctors_and_hospitals\" width=\ "500\" height=\ "100\" class=\ "textWrapFaq\">
<p>XpertMatch (%) reflects our
  <br>assessment how closely the
  <br>doctor's profile matches your query.
  <br>
</p>
<img img-cache src=\ "assets/images/c2.gif\" alt=\ "personalized_list_of_Xpert_doctors_and_hospitals\" class=\ "textWrapFaqLeft\" width=\ "500\" height=\ "100\">
<p>The doctor's profile includes 1)
  <b0r>clinical expertise, 2) research
    <br>contributions, and 3) educational
    <br>contributions and leadership.</p>
<img img-cache src=\ "assets/images/c3.gif\" alt=\ "personalized_list_of_Xpert_doctors_and_hospitals\" width=\ "500\" height=\ "80\" class=\ "textWrapFaq\">
<br>
<p>Within each of the above 3 key
  <br>areas, we further assess
  <br>whether the experience reflects
  <br>experience in your disease or
  <br>related diseases. All this
  <br>information led to a 3
  <br>dimensional database of XpertMatch (%) for each of the 5000 diseases for each of the one million doctors i.e. 5 billion XpertMatch (%)!.</p>",
```

Comment: Can you set a up a JS Fiddle for this issue?

Comment: I put the image there

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/L0hnuLjx/